# Oracle Select All (*) with additional field return error : ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle

My table design something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE "IMART_SYSTEM"."TMI_ISD_AUDIT_TRAIL" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USER_ID" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "ACTION" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE), 
    "SUCCESS" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "DATE_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6)
    )
```

I want to select all of fields and I want add some additional formatted field, but return error.

This is my Query :

```
select TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss' ) myDateTime,* from TMI_ISD_AUDIT_TRAIL
```

Error Occured:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 55
```

Can Oracle doing that? Select * with additional fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use table alias ("t" in my example)
- minutes format is `mi`, not `mm`

---

```
select to_char(t.date_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') mydatetime, t.*
from tmi_isd_audit_trail t;
```